# how can I hide the seekbar when it was not used by user in android

Tags: android, android-animation, fadeout

I need to hide a seek-bar automatically after few second.

I used seek-bar in my audio player to control volume, I wanna hide the seek-bar after few second with fade-out animation when it's not used by use

Comment: Why don't you just do it? There are probably some similar questions here on how to fade an element out. As well as how to do something after a period of time. You can probably use 2-3 different questions/answers and figure it out.

Comment: You right, Thanks